# Navigation Bar Hidden on Segue/Push (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I used the following code to redirect from a child to the parent (except I had to load different data on the parent--think of it as a chat app with a button to see your profile and you can click on some other friend of yours to redirect to a different chat i.e. a different dataset). I initially used

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "parent") as! UIViewController
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(popOverVC, animated: true)
```

But that allowed me to go back to previous chat by swiping left (I tried disabling that by hiding back button, using

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

and it didn't disable the swipe back feature either (I used it in ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear, ViewWillLayoutSubViews and still it didn't work; I could still swipe back to previous chat). So I tried using the following and while it worked, my nav bar would disappear.

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

worked when I used the pushViewController (but it would still let me swipe back) and it doesn't work when I use the root VC (but it disables the swipe back)

Here is the rootVC method I'm talking about:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0] as UIWindow
    popOverVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
  window.rootViewController = popOverVC
```

Comment: so you want to disable swipe left back ?

Answer (score 1):

As most of the iOS Users go back by swiping and less by pressing the back button.
For it would be more reasonable to use a modal segue instead of a push segue which is not that big of a transfer. You can just disable back button.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: It still lets me swipe back even though there is no back button. Can you briefly explain what you mean by modular segue? I assumed you meant just leading to the new viewcontroller through Storyboard, but if I do that, then the navigation bar doesn't appear (Even though the back feature is disabled). So essentially I still have the same problem I described in the question